# Azure pipeline with multiple environments

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My *dotnetcore* app has one appsettings.json per environment (*appsettings.json* and *appsettings.Development.json* for example) and I would like to take advantage of this on my pipeline.

I see 2 options for the pipeline:

```
Build Artifact for Dev -> Deploy on Dev -> Build Artifact for Prod -> Deploy on Prod
```

or

```
Build Artifact -> Deploy on Dev -> Deploy on Prod
```

For the first option, I could set the environment as a parameter for the build.

For the second option, how could I build the App only once, and set the environment according to the current deployment step? Taking advantage of the multiple *appsettings.json* I have.

And finally, are these approaches aligned with the best practices? If not, what would be the best practices for pipelines with multiple environments?

Comment: Did you find a way to accomplish this? I'm also attempting to make use of `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json` through the build pipeline per environment? If you have, please post it so we can all benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally we can generate a single artifact, then deploy the artifact to different environments and perform the different transformations at any environment within it's own stage release phase. That means we can change and override the settings which defined in the `appsettings.json` in each release environment.

Please refer to [File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops) on how to do the transformation with .json files.

Besides, we can try to install the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens&targetId=4ace6815-ca0a-4926-92f1-862643b5c950) extension, then use Replace Tokens task to load and change the settings defined in the `appsettings.json` file in each release environment/stage.

You can also transform the settings or use [File Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task) to create a new `appsettings.json`file to overwrite the existing one.

Below blogs for your reference:

- [Replace appsetting tokens in config files with Build & Release
  Management in VSTS (TFS)](https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/replace-appsettings-token-configfiles-build-release-tfs-vsts)
- [Transform configurations in a .NET Core 2.2 Web API using Azure
  DevOps](https://medium.com/cheranga/transform-configurations-in-a-net-core-2-2-web-api-using-azure-devops-8febc8796713)
- [Using custom appsettings.json with ASP.NET Core integration
  tests](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-integration-tests-appsettings/)

Comment: Using file transforms it's a way to do it but doesn't look like a straightforward way to do it. Because while building your app if you define your env as "Development", your app would use the appsettings.Development.json. I was looking for an approach similar to this.

Comment: So, have you tried the File Creator extension mentioned in above answer, it can create a new *.json file for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with Azure AppConfiguration and add it as an extra source for the configuration. This way your building/releasing process stays extremely simple.

See this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet-core

It's very powerful: you can select only part of the configuration (through filters), you can have feature flags, and you can have secrets (from linked key vaults).