# Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline - Deploy SSRS reports, use KeyVault parameterize Data Source Connection

Tags: azure-devops, reporting-services, cicd

I'm looking at using a DevOps Pipeline to deploy an SSRS solution from a Repository to different environments.
I've seen this on the marketplace.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mmajcica.deploy-ssrs
Is there a way after getting connection strings for say Dev, Test & Prod I could push them into the config file?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a variable group and [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbash#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault), you can store your `Data Source Connection` with different variables (`Dev`, `Test` & `Prod` ), then you can use the variables to replace the Data Source connection string in the config file using [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) or [Replace Text in Source Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Samayas.azuredevops-samayas-replaceinfiles) extension.

Just try to install the extensions, then add the task to replace the `Data Source Connection` from the config file using the specific variable before the `Deploy MS SQL SSRS Report` task.

For example, add 3 stages to deploy to `Dev`, `Test` & `Prod` environments separately. Every time it will load the default config file, and replace the string to it for further using.

Reference [Azure pipeline with multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049190/azure-pipeline-with-multiple-environments/60052143#60052143)